# F# Fable Fetch Correctly Unwrap Promise to another Promise type

Tags: f#, fable-f#

I need to request data from several URLs and then use the results.

I am using plain Fable 3 with the [Fable-Promise](https://github.com/fable-compiler/fable-promise) and Fable-Fetch libraries.

I have worked out how to fetch from multiple URLs and combine the results into a single Promise that I can then use to update the UI (the multiple results need to be drawn only once).

But if one of the fetch errors then the whole thing falls over. Ideally I'd like to use `tryFetch` and then propagate the `Result<TermData, None | Exception>` but nothing I do seems to compile.

How exactly do I use `tryFetch` and then unwrap the result with a second `let!` in the CE? (The comments explain more)

```
module App

open Browser.Dom
open App
open System.Collections.Generic
open System.Text.RegularExpressions
open Fetch
open System

type TermData =
    abstract counts : int []
    abstract scores : int []
    abstract term : string
    abstract allWords : bool

type QueryTerm =
    { mutable Term: string
      mutable AllWords: bool }

let loadSingleSeries (term: QueryTerm) =
    promise {
        let url =
            $"/api/plot/{term.Term}?allWords={term.AllWords}"

        // Works but doesn't handle errors.
        let! plotData = fetch url [] // type of plotData: Response

        // let plotDataResult = tryFetch url []

        // This ideally becomes Promise<Result<TermData, None>>
        // let unwrapped = match plotDataResult with
        //     | Ok res -> Ok (res.json<TermData>()) // type: Promise<TermData>
        //     | Error err -> ??? // tried Error (Promise.create(fun resolve reject -> resolve None)) among others

        let! result = plotData.json<TermData>() // type of result: TermData
        return result 
    }

let dataArrays =
    parsed // type Dictionary<int, TermData>
    |> Seq.map (fun term -> loadSingleSeries term.Value)
    |> Promise.Parallel
    |> Promise.map (fun allData -> console.log(allData))

    // Here we will handle None when we have it
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't have much Fable experience, but if I understand your question correctly, I think the following should work:

```ml
let loadSingleSeries (term: QueryTerm) =
    promise {
        let url =
            $"/api/plot/{term.Term}?allWords={term.AllWords}"

        let! plotDataResult = tryFetch url []

        match plotDataResult with
            | Ok resp ->
                let! termData = resp.json<TermData>()
                return Ok termData
            | Error ex ->
                return Error ex
    }
```

The idea here is that if you get an error, you simply propagate that error in the new `Result` value. This returns a `Promise<Result<TermData, Exception>>`, as you requested.

**Update**: Fixed return type using a second `let!`.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, the problem here is `res.json<TermData>` is a `Promise<TermData>` so the return type for this method is `Promise<Result<Promise<TermData>, exn>>` rather than a flattened `Promise<Result<TermData, exn>>`.

Comment: Ah, of course. Easy enough to fix. Please see my updated answer. This is is the only answer that allows you to use the `promise` builder with `tryFetch` via a second `let!`, as you requested in your question.

Comment: Thank you, that did the trick! A lot of my confusion was trying to get a multi-line statement in the `match` branch. It's one of those things that is just impossible to Google for.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't run this code but looking at the docs it looks like you need to use [Promise.catch](https://fable.io/fable-promise/reference/Fable.Promise/global-promise.html#catch)

```
let loadSingleSeries (term: QueryTerm) =
    promise {
        let url =
            $"/api/plot/{term.Term}?allWords={term.AllWords}"

        
        let! plotDataResult = 
            fetch url [] 
            |> Promise.map Ok  // Wraps the "happy path" in a Result.Ok
            |> Promise.catch (fun err -> 
                  //handle the error
                  Error err)

        return
             match plotDataResult with
             | Ok res -> ...
             | Error err -> ...
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, this was fairly close to the result I ended up with, the problem is still unwrapping the `plotDataResult` since to convert it to JSON requires a second await. I ended up using `Promise.bind` for this https://stackoverflow.com/a/69796640/1775471

Answer (score 0):

I ended up having to use the pipeline rather than CE approach for this as follows:

```
let loadSingleSeries (term: QueryTerm) =
    let url =
        $"/api/plot/{term.Term}?allWords={term.AllWords}"

    let resultPromise =
        fetch url []
        |> Promise.bind (fun response ->
            let arr = response.json<TermData> ()
            arr)
        |> Promise.map (Ok)
        |> Promise.catch (Error)

    resultPromise
```

The key was using `Promise.bind` to convert the first promise to get the `Response` to the promise of `Promise<TermData>`. The `map` and `catch` then convert to a `Promise<Result<TermData, exn>>`.